# Why In Microsoft SQL, Icons does not appear in Solution Explorer

Tags: sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server for a while. on my PC everything is fine but on my Laptop the Solution Explorer's Icon does not appear .
[Solution explorer on my Laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwKsj.jpg)

[Solution explorer on my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugj7o.jpg)

Comment: If by saying "icon" you mean the section, the you can try *Ctrl + Alt + L* or go to  View -> Solution Explorer. Click on it and it will appear

Comment: This looks like a Windows version, or SSMS version, or SSMS configuration issue. The Icon is there, just not colored like your connection icon...

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have it selected in the toolbar options:

[image]

Comment: I checked out, it 'is already selected but still same as before.

Comment: I can see from the screenshots that you are not running the same version of SSMS on both systems.  Therein lies the problem